# Confusion between PSK and QPSK

Tags: digital-communications, modulation

What is the difference between PSK (Phase Shift Keying) and QPSK (Quadrature Phase Shift Keying)? Doesn't PSK need quadrature component for its working?

Comment: PSK is not necessarily QPSK. QPSK is PSK. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Higher-order_PSK

They all have inphase and quadrature components.

Comment: Your question is really good though. We often don't think on these lines with established terminologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QPSK modulation is a PSK modulation with exactly 4 constellation points.  The constellation points for QPSK are normally at $\left(\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}j\right) $

Comment: In [https://www.slideshare.net/sristykp/modulation-46756444], it says that pi/4 QPSK has more than 4 constellation points. I'm confused